# Laravel 8 routes to controllers. SEO friendly URL structure

Tags: php, laravel, url, url-routing, laravel-8

I am trying to figure out how to achieve a specific URL structure in a Laravel 8 project and the necessary route to achieve this. What I want is:

```
// Example urls to listings in the business directory.
// These urls should be routed to the directory controller.
www.domain-name.com/example-business-name-d1.html
www.domain-name.com/example-business-name-d15.html
www.domain-name.com/example-business-name-d100.html
www.domain-name.com/example-business-name-d123.html
www.domain-name.com/example-business-name-d432.html

// Example urls to articles/posts in the blog.
// These urls should be routed to the posts controller.
www.domain-name.com/example-post-name-p5.html
www.domain-name.com/example-post-name-p11.html
www.domain-name.com/example-post-name-p120.html
www.domain-name.com/example-post-name-p290.html
www.domain-name.com/example-post-name-p747.html

// We want to avoid the more traditional:
www.domain-name.com/directory/example-business-name-1.html
www.domain-name.com/blog/example-post-name-5.html
```

This is because we don't want the strings “directory” or “blog” contained in the url for every listing or blog post. Search engine results work better without it.

So far I am using a catch-all route {any} at the bottom of the web.php routes file to “catch all” routes that get that far. I then manipulate the string provided by the path to get the ID and single character token from the end of the urls. I then have these 2 variables but can figure out how to pass these onto the right controllers!

Or am I being really dumb and there is a much better way of achieving this?

```
Route::get('{any}', function($any = null){

    // Break up the url into seperate parts.
    $pieces = explode("-", $any);
    $pieces = array_reverse($pieces);
    $piece =  $pieces[0];

    // Remove the .html
    $piece = substr($piece, 0, -5);

    // Get the two parts of the identifier.
    $id = substr($piece, 1);
    $token = substr($piece, 0, 1);

    // Call correct controller based on the token.
    switch ($token) {
        case "d":
            // HERE I WANT TO PASS THE ID ON TO THE SHOW ACTION OF THE DIRECTORY CONTROLLER 
        break;
        case "p":
            // HERE I WANT TO PASS THE ID ON TO THE SHOW ACTION OF THE POSTS CONTROLLER 
        break;
        default:
            return abort(404);
        break;
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you share the other route definitions you've got already? Why do you need such a complex way of route matching after all?

Comment: _Search engine results work better without it._ Do they, though…? I’m pretty sure “directories” help search engines understand the structure and hierarchy of your content.

Comment: Stackoverflow uses the format you're considering as bad practice, and they seem to always hit top search results

Comment: you want to use `.html` .?  in laravel

Comment: @MartinBean you are right. Having “directories” in a URL does help describe the structure and content. I will still use this for the URL on the landing page of the directory and the associated paginated pages. When I say _"Search engine results work better without it."_ I am referring specifically to how the user sees and interprets   the SERPS. I think it's preferable to display the full business name in the URL that Google displays and if the word "directory" remains in the URL then the business name may be truncated. It's a marginal point and I guess comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @KamleshPaul you are right that this is unnecessary, again just personal preference. I am probably silly but I think there is a small usability gain from seeing in the address bar what I am expecting to get. HTML, PDF, etc... It also helps to visualize it as an endpoint, a file. as distinct from a directory, list or other collection of resources.

Comment: Yup. Google’s refined their algorithm to this “gaming” for over two decades now. The repeated business name in the filename-style URLs is probably going to be a signal for spam rather than bring any SEO benefits.

Comment: @GeorgeLitchfield if you want ot use `.html` file just put those in `public` folder it will work as web work for `.html` file

Answer (score 6):

I would split the path into 2 variables (`$slug` and `$id`) and directly pass it to the controller.

```php
Route::get('{slug}-d{id}.html', 'DirectoryController@show')
    ->where(['slug' => '([a-z\-]+)', 'id' => '(\d+)']);

Route::get('{slug}-p{id}.html', 'PostController@show')
    ->where(['slug' => '([a-z\-]+)', 'id' => '(\d+)']);
```

And in your controllers

```php
class DirectoryController
{
    public function show(string $slug, int $id) {}
}

class PostController
{
    public function show(string $slug, int $id) {}
}
```

Comment: This will cearly not work for any url with a different string than 'example-business-name' and 'example-post-name'....

Comment: This is a very nice solution, perhaps the `html` is a little verbose though heh

Comment: This works for me. Thanks. I tweaked the regex a bit so that it works with numbers too. `([÷a-z0-9\-]+)`. Works now for all of the test business names I have.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways of achieving this result:

### Create an intermediate controller

```php
Route::get('{path}', 'CheckPathController@redirect')
```

Then in your `CheckPathController` you do all the checks and your call the proper controller action:

```
public function redirect(Request $request, $path) {
  // Your checks on $path, extract $id and content type

  if($isPost) {
     $controller = resolve(PostController::class);
     return $controller->show($request, $id);
  }

  if($isBusiness) {
     $controller = resolve(BusinessController::class);
     return $controller->show($request, $id);
  }

  // No matches, error 404
  abort(404);
}
```

### Complex regex

see: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

I'm not a regexp master, this should be a basic was to match any `{word}-{word}-...-p{id}.html` pattern but it will break in case of unexpected chars

```php
Route::get('{path}', 'PostController::show')
   ->where(['path' => '([\w]*-)*p[0-9]+\.html$']);

Route::get('{path}', 'BusinessController::show')
   ->where(['path' => '([\w]*-)*d[0-9]+\.html$']);
```

Note that in this case, you controller will receive the pull `$path` string, so you will need to extract the id there.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the slug using regex

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'YourController@methodName')->where(['any' => '.*(-d(.*?)\.).*']);
```

Repeated with `p`

Then when you pickup your $site in your controller method you can use regex to grab the site.

```
public function methodName($site)
{
    preg_match('/.*(-(d(.*?))\.).*/', $site, $parts); //or something similar, $parts[2] will have what you want
}
```

**OR**

This will give your controller method d{number} or p{number}

```
Route::get('/{site}', function($site) {
    $code = preg_match('/.*(-(d(.*?)|p(.*?))\.).*/', $site, $parts) ? $parts[2] : null;

    $controllerName = 'ControllerA';
    if(isset($code) && !is_null($code) && Str::contains($code, 'p')) {
        $controllerName = 'ControllerB';
    }

    $controller = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\Application\\' . $controllerName);

    return $controller->callAction('methodName', $params = ['code' => $code]);
})->where(['site' => '.*(-(d|p)(.*?)\.).*']);
```